# Bug in code snippet in revision page

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When checking answer edit history in Stack Overflow, the changes in the code snippet are displayed correctly, but on pressing "Run Code Snippet" The first line was not being recognized by the snippet and it appeared as text in the output. And on inspecting the code, I saw that the snippet was just running the old version of the code and not reflecting the changes.

[image]

This is a screenshot of url : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45006822/revisions

Like here the change in the first line of the HTML, comes as text. And the code executed by the snippet is actually the red one.

Comment: Why did you hide actual post id?

Comment: Yeah, please make up your mind whether or not you want to link to the revisions page.

Comment: Updated the link with the id of the actual page.

Comment: When I use the latest revision of that answer from the history page and click on run snippet, then the output looks fine.

Comment: For me it comes as shown in the image. And if I inspect the code with Inspect Element, it shows that the code version is the older one.

Comment: I see it as well, using Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit). Look at the revision history, view the changes as "inline", then run the snippet. Compare the results to *side by side* where both snippets return the *latest (??!??!)* version.

Comment: Late `+1`. I didn't see the post here after you delete it on MSE

Comment: @SagarV Haha. Cheers.